# Customising/Localizin the error text in Azure AD B2C custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am unable to customize the following error message in azure ad b2c custom policy.
This message comes in password reset policy ,if entered email address doesn't exist.
to localize this i used following id but its not working.

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">sample text</LocalizedString>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different string id - `UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist`.

```
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" 
            StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">sample test.</LocalizedString>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids

Comment: Glad I could help. If your question was answered by this, you should accept it by clicking the check mark. This way, we can help keep the focus on questions which still have no answer