# Is there a way to force email verification in Azure B2C before allowing user to click Create or update the vague error message when not verified?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C Sign up and sing in policy and would like to improve the user experience for creating an account. If a new user does not click the Send verification code button and fills out the remainder of the form fields when creating a new Azure AD B2C account they receive a "A required field is missing. Please fill out all required fields and try again.":

[image: screenshot with ambiguous error message]

Most users are confused on what the missing required field is, as there is no input simply a button to Send verification code. I would like to either force a user to click the button and verify their email before they are able to click the Create button or provide a more descriptive error message like: "A required field is missing or the Email Verification Code has not been sent/verified".

Does anyone know how I can do either of these without going down the custom page content route?

Comment: Thank you for all the details kavyasaraboju. As I feared the only ways (at least that I could discern from you answer and the information contained within all the B2C documentation) to change the UI or error message is via custom page content or a custom policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ,Signin sign up **user flow** ,error messages  or flow can be customized only through  [user interface with HTML templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow) ,which looks like don't prefer as you said
*"without going down the custom page content route"*

You can make use of localization , if you use Custom policies which uses TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

The IDs for a content definition with an ID of api.localaccountsignup. [Localization string IDs - Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-user-interface-elements)  /  [localization-string-ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids)

- You need to make changes in the appropriate “api.xxx” action. In this
  case, it’s “api.localaccountsignup”.
- The XML changes to the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file are:

*ID :  error_requiredFieldMissing

Default value  :  A required field is missing. Please fill out all required fields and try again.*

```
<LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
...
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="error_requiredFieldMissing">A required field is missing. Please fill out all required fields and try again.</LocalizedString>
...
<LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
```

We may need to **Change** to

```
<Localization Enabled="true">
  <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
    <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
  </SupportedLanguages>
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">

   #Change the error message here
    <LocalizedStrings>
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="error_requiredFieldMissing">A required field is missing or the Email Verification Code has not been sent/verified as not clicked on send verification code</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>

  </LocalizedResources>
</Localization>
```

Please **Refer**:

1. [Customising the message/error text in Azure AD B2C custom policies | by Rory Braybrook](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/customising-the-message-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-d1e1ff2640d3#:%7E:text=Customising%20the%20message%2Ferror%20text%20in%20Azure%20AD%20B2C,the%20text%20into%20another%20language%20is%20described%20here.)
2. [get-a-proper-error-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609196/how-to-get-a-proper-error-message-in-azure-b2c-built-in-signup-flow)  or [customising/localizin the error in b2c-custom-policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933636/customising-localizin-the-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies)
3. [Localization string IDs - verification-display-control| Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#verification-display-control-example)

Answer (score 0):

Separate the email verification code step from the actual signup, might be a workaround for you.

The below custom policy shows how to achieve this:

[Separate the Email Verification and User Registration into 2 separate screens](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup)

- [Live Demo](https://b2clivedemo.b2clogin.com/b2clivedemo.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_SplitEmailVerificationAndSignUp/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=cfaf887b-a9db-4b44-ac47-5efff4e2902c&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login)